# Funcao codeigniter com sql

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho uma função chamada pneus na model do codeigniter

E na mesma model tenho outra função que eu preciso chamar o cod da função pneus

Alguém pode me dizer como faço isso aqui um exemplo do que quero fazer...

`$this->db->where('xcod1 = ', $this->pneus->cod);`

Comment: Está a aceder à tabela? Não terá de especificar a tabela da BD

Comment: Não ficou mto claro qual é o problema, poderia explicar melhor e colocar as partes importantes do model?

Comment: Digamos a sql é essa : $this->db->where('xcod1 = ', Aqui eu quero pegar um cod); E esse cod vem de uma outra função ai quero saber como posso pegar fiz usando $this->nomeDaFuncao->cod;

Comment: Faça a função retornar o valor, depois passe ele para frente.

Comment: E como passo ela ?

Answer (score 0):

O **model** do **CI** ele serve apenas para comunicação com **DB**, quem gerenciar e chama as funções são os **controller**

Pois bem nessa sua função:

```
$this->db->where('xcod1 = ', $this->pneus->cod);
```

o correto seria, sem o sinal de **"="** ficando assim:

```
$this->db->where('xcod1', $this->pneus->cod);
```

mas de onde vem o objeto **pneus**, acredito q esteja ai!